# Multiple routers and VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I am trying to increase the security of my soho network. I have setup a couple of vlans (I think) so I can segregate work, home, children, guest, and IoT devices. The vlans are pretty simple and all but one just routes the wireless radio to the wan (the other vlan also includes the ethernet ports on the router for a couple of devices without wifi). Each vlan then has a separate ssid and subnet on the network.

I pay extra money for fast internet 300+ Mbps and while no individual "subnet" needs this speed, there are often a couple of kids and a wife streaming while I am trying to do work. I would have no problem if the bandwidth of each subnet was limited to 50 Mbps and each person was on a different subnet.

The plan was to setup the router as a client for a VPN service like ExpressVPN and be done with it. I like this idea because then I can go back to ignoring the individual devices. The problem I see is if the router acts as a single device, I think the best I can hope for is something like 70 Mbps through the VPN. The VPN service, however, lets me have multiple devices.

If instead of vlans, I bought additional routers could, each of these connect to the VPN to increase the throughput (they would plug into the "main" router which would not use the VPN)? If this is the case, can I do it in software (the router is running openwrt)?

Comment: Are you suggesting you might have to split 70 Mbps by three if you have three devices on one router, but if you have three routers each running the VPN going into a main router you might be able to get 210 Mbps total?  Short answer is: probably not but it depends

Comment: @LTPCGO I naively assumed that the reported speeds were per device and not per account.

Comment: It might well be more like the route between you and the VPN server (and then VPN -> external site) is limited at that speed.  Or the encapsulation required for the VPN limits the rate.  There's lots of potential bottlenecks and it would need actual testing to find out what is the actual one.  It's also potentially a bad idea to serve all your traffic this way if you want to use Netflix for example.